# Javascript: Can you check if an object has a key which contains another key

Tags: javascript

Take the below object

```
var obj = {
    hello: 1,
    helloWorld: 2
}
```

Is it possible, knowing only that `obj.hello` exists, to check if another key contains the same word?

I do not need to know what the other key is, only that one exists.

Comment: Yes, it is possible -- `Object.keys(obj)` will give you all the keys in an array, which you can check by the usual methods.

Comment: `'hello' in obj`

Comment: @mplungjan Since they want to find a key containing an already existing key, that may return the original instead of the new. Use this instead: `Object.keys(obj).find(key => key !== otherKey && key.includes(otherKey)) `

Comment: @Keldan Chapman thats what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that,

```js
var obj = {
  hello: 1,
  helloWorld: 2
}
let exist = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => key.includes('hello') && key !== 'hello').length > 0;

console.log(exist);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the `Object.keys`, and filtering it.

```js
var obj = {
    hello: 1,
    helloWorld: 2,
    anotherKey: 3
}

var keysWithHello = Object.keys(obj).filter(x => x.includes("hello"));

console.log(keysWithHello.length ? "Object has keys with hello" : "No keys with hello")
```